# The mapping $T:(a,b)→ (at^2,bt^3)$ of $V_2$ (R) into itself is a linear transformation.

Tags: linear-transformations

The mapping $T:(a,b)→ (at^2,bt^3)$ of $V_2$ (R) into itself is a linear transformation.
 
is it a correct statement or not ?

Comment: Can you check conditions for linearity: is $T((a,b)+(c,d))=T((a,b))+T((c,d))$, etc.?

Comment: Actually it is not the conventional *statement* of a mapping definition.  Is that the point of what you were asking, or were you asking whether the presumed definition produces a mapping $T$ that *is* a linear transformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A transformation $L(x) $ is linear if $L(α1x+α2y)=α1L(x)+α2L(y)$, where $α1$ and $α2$ are constants.

Let us check if this holds for the given transformation.

Let $T:(a,b) $and $T:(c,d) $be two transformations and $α1$ and $α2$ two constants.

Then, $$T(α1(a,b)+α2(c,d))=T((α1a,α1b)+(α2c,α2d))$$

$$=T(α1a+α2c,α1b+α2d)$$

$$=((α1a+α2c)t^2,(α1b,α2d)t^3)$$

$$=(α1at^2+α2ct^2,α1bt^3,α2dt^3)$$

$$=(α1at^2,α1bt^3)+(α2ct^2,α2dt^3)$$

$$=α1(at^2,bt^3)+α2(ct^2,dt^3)$$

$$=α1T(a,b)+α2T(c,d).$$

The mapping $T:(a,b)→(at^2,bt^3)$ of $V2(R)$ into itself is a linear transformation.

Comment: Presumably you want to learn a little more $\LaTeX$ syntax as [introduced here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).  This would allow using *subscripts* like $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ as well as arbitrary exponents/superscripts.